# failing to insert a json object into mysql using prepared statement (works without)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Field   Type        Null    Key     Default     Extra   
id      int(11)     NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
form    char(255)   NO              NULL    
valori  json        NO              NULL    
mail    tinyint(1)  NO              0
```

and using an ajax call I am trying to insert a new record in this table.

sample data I am trying to insert are:

> "form":"new_field"
>
> "valori":"{\"status\":500,\"message\":\"Nuovo+campo+creato+correttamente\",\"nome\":\"ffnfaojo\",\"label\":\"vnsovnos\",\"descrizione\":\"**vnsovnos:+**nosnvoisnvow\",\"autore\":\"1\"}"
>
> "mail":"true"

the json array is sent in a stringified format.

The php code:

```
try{
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO segnalazioni (form,valori,mail) VALUES (:form, :valori, :mail)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':form', $form);
  $stmt->bindParam(':valori', $valori);
  $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $db);

  $stmt->execute();  
}
catch(PDOexception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

will produce no output and no insert into the db

If I send the plain json instead of the stringified version PHP raise the array to string conversion error:

> Array to string conversion in ... on line 21

that is where I bind the json value. I am missing something here but since it is the first time I store a json I need some help. 
NOTE that I know what are the side effects on storing a JSON and this is one of those situation where these doesn't apply: This is kind of a log and data are supposed to remain immutable and searched by form column only. No operations on the json data on the db side

EDIT: the ajax:

```
}).done(function(data) {
            if(data.status==200){
              //campo creato correttamente
//not in scope here
            }else{
              //non sono riuscito a caricare i dati
              $('#modal-text').html('<p class="text-danger">'+data.message+'</p><b>Dati per il debug</b> (saranno inviati in automatico nella mail):<br>');
              var risposta = data;
              $("#modal-text").append(JSON.stringify(data));
              $('#message').modal('show');
              //default carico solo la segnalazione a db
              var mail = false;
              //utente sceglie di inviare il modale;
              $('.segnalazione').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr('id')=='error_submit'){
                  mail= true;
                }
              //effettuo il caricamento
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'segnalazione.php',
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {form:'new_field', valori:risposta, mail: mail},
                  dataType: 'json'
                });
              });
```

and the edited part of the segnalazione.php:

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$form=$_POST['form'];
$valori=json_encode($_POST['valori']);
$mail=$_POST['mail'];
try{
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO segnalazioni (form,valori,mail) VALUES (:form, :valori, :mail)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':form', $form);
  $stmt->bindParam(':valori', $valori);
  $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $db);

  $stmt->execute();  
}
catch(PDOexception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

is leading to:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in ... on line 24

EDIT 2:
what is actually posted:

array(3) { ["form"]=> string(9) "new_field" ["valori"]=> array(6) { ["status"]=> string(3) "500" ["message"]=> string(32) "Nuovo campo creato correttamente" ["nome"]=> string(5) "pippo" ["label"]=> string(5) "pluto" ["descrizione"]=> string(22) "pluto: paperino" ["autore"]=> string(1) "1" } ["mail"]=> string(4) "true" }

Edit 3: 
using the data echoed by my php for:
    $form=$_POST['form'];
    $valori=json_encode($_POST['valori']);
    $mail=$_POST['mail'];

i built the query that is working fine in mysql workbench and the line is inserted as i would expect

```
insert into segnalazioni SET form='new_field', valori='{"status":"500","message":"Nuovo campo creato correttamente","nome":"pippo","label":"pluto","descrizione":"pluto: <\/b>paperino","autore":"1"}', mail=1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211323/discussion-on-question-by-lelio-faieta-failing-to-insert-a-json-object-into-mysq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit for this answer goes to @num8er that realized that when you bind a JSON object in a prepared statement to be inserted in a JSON type field, you have to specify that it has to be treated as string.

so changing

```
$stmt->bindParam(':valori', $valori);
```

to

```
$stmt->bindParam(':valori', $valori, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

did the trick.